# Openshift hot deploy

Tags: openshift

I deployed a Node.js app using openshift with the hot deploy enabled.
But it looks like the supervisor doesn't reload my app, I have to restart it manually.
Furthermore my app is not restarted after a crash.. someone has any idea how I could make this work ?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you disable hot deploy?

Comment: Because the app is completely down during a deployment without using hop deploy..

Comment: You may enable Jenkins. It will keep your old app running while new app is deploying. But you will need more containers for that.